# I cannot get my simple products in the right order within my configurable products

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, simple-product

I have set up configurable products, which consists of simple products. I want my simple products listed in order of dimensions. But when I add a new product, I see it listed at the bottom of the list instead in the middle where it belongs.

I have a screenshot attached that displays the issue. Please give me the golden tip. Thank you in advance.

[image]

Thank you for your response.

Comment: have you tried giving proper `position`ing at `Catalog > Manage Attributes > your_attribute > attribute_value`?

Comment: Strangely, the attribute sort does not work on my `v1.9.1.0` with sample data from Magento.

Comment: This is a bug in Magento 1.9.1 - http://magentosupport.help/knowledgebase/solved-sort-configurable-product-attribute-options-and-dropdowns/ and seems not to be fixed in 1.9.2 yet - http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/Magento_Community_Edition_User_Guide.html#magento/release-notes-ce-1.9.2.html

Answer (score 1):

Simple Products are listed in the order of their ID number.

When a simple product is created it is given an ID number. The next simple item that is created is given an ID number incremented by one. The simple products are then displayed in chronological order.

Comment: Can't this be changed? When I need to add a forgotten or new priduct?

Comment: I don't think so, and I think that this is a huge design flaw.

Comment: The position sorter located in Catalog>Manage Attributes>your attribute>manage options didn't work for me. It didn't change the order of the options as they were displayed on front end.It only changed the order on the options in the back-end manage options pane. The issue I see is if this position sorter doesn't change the order, then where would the position sorter that does change the order be located for each attribute you create?

Comment: It just seems not to work ... That's odd since many people have to deal with this issue.

Comment: Agree. I didn't have as many simple products as you, so I just deleted the ones that were wrongly placed, and then recreated them in the right order so they would have ascending IDs. Other option would be to modify IDs in database. Neither of these options are ideal...

Answer (score 1):

This issue is as a result of a bug introduced in Magento CE 1.9.1 release wherein the 'Position' parameter on attribute Label/Options is being disregarded.

Instead the sort order of the displayed drop-down options is being determined by the SKUs or IDs(not sure) of the associated simple products.

Fortunately an easy fix is available at http://merchantprotocol.com/knowledgebase/solved-sort-configurable-product-attribute-options-and-dropdowns/

Quoting from therein :

> Step 1 : Creating the overriding file structure
>
> You will need to create the following folder structure, because most likely it does not exist. This file structure will override the original file and allow you to maintain an upgrade safe patch to your Magento installation. I’ve bolded the local folder in this breadcrumb because it’s where you will need to start creating folders.
>
> root/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Type/Configurable/Attribute/
>
> Step 2: Step 2 : Creating the patched file
>
> Inside of the last folder that you created, Attribute, you will need to create a new file called Collection.php and paste into the contents of my patch below.
>
> File available at https://gist.github.com/Jonathonbyrd/407d57b2a458bbbd7f92/raw/c12062f72b0e46724be790fa4be70a8abdfad21f/Collection.php

Bug report (requires login): http://www.magentocommerce.com/products/bug-tracking/issue/index/id/413/

Found a few other solutions and updates related to the same problem herein as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27270918/magento-1-9-1-not-sorting-configurable-product-attributes-dropdown-by-position